# Node with NGINX reverse proxy seems to kill connection even when configured using long timeout

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have this Node app running behind an NGINX reverse proxy. My Node app functionality is to download a large XLS file that consumes for about 80-120 seconds. It works locally without NGINX, but when I used NGINX, it seems that it just hangs and gives me timeout error.

I use MongoDB and Mongoose as a database in my Node App, and it will query the database to download the XLSX

Here is a piece of NGINX configuration:

```
keepalive_timeout   70;
  

  client_max_body_size 16m;

  location    / {

    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length  1100;
    gzip_buffers  4 32k;
    gzip_types    text/css text/javascript text/xml text/plain text/x-component application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json application/xml  application/rss+xml font/truetype application/x-font-ttf font/opentype application/vnd.ms-fontobject image/svg+xml;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level  6;

    proxy_pass  http://indorelawan-80;
    
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Request-Start $msec;
    proxy_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_buffers 4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    proxy_connect_timeout 600;
    proxy_send_timeout 600;
    proxy_read_timeout 600;
    send_timeout 600;
  }
```

As you can see, it is using proxy_send_timeout and proxy_read_timeout for 600 seconds. When I tried it in local (without NGINX), it will download the XLS for about 83 seconds or so. But, in Production using NGINX, it will halt and return timeout. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I moved to using queues like [BullMQ](https://github.com/optimalbits/bull) instead.